# Avoid accessing the same location twice/clicking twice, TkInter Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using the Text Widget feature in TkInter to "save" lines/paragraphs and append to a list.

```
with open(fname1, "rt", encoding='latin1') as in_file:
    readable_file = in_file.read()

line_list = []


def grab_line(event):
    line_beginning = textPad.index("current linestart")
    line_ending = textPad.index("current lineend")
    line = textPad.get(line_beginning, line_ending)
    line_list.append(line)

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, width=750, height=1)
root.minsize(600,600)  # sets the size of the actual window
frame.pack()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(1.0, readable_file)
text.bind('<Button-1>', grab_line)
root.mainloop()
```

Is there anyway to make sure that I do not select the same paragraph twice? Perhaps there's a TkInter function...

Otherwise, one would check the list/dictionary contents and delete if there are duplicates.

Comment: if you mean double click in very short time then you could compare current `line_beginning` with `previous_line_beginning`

Comment: or maybe you should use `<Double-Button-1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is add a tag on the selected block of text. You can then check for the presence of that tag. You could also use the tag to highlight the code so that the user knows they've already clicked on it.

```
# this step is optional; you don't have to configure a tag
# before adding it to a range of text
text.tag_configure("already_selected", background="yellow")
...
text.tag_add("already_selected", line_beginning, line_ending)
```

To check if the tag applies to where they clicked, use the `tag_names` method. For example:

```
if "already_selected" in text.tag_names("current"):
    ...
```

Comment: Highlighting the code is a great idea! Thanks. What I ended up doing to avoid duplicates was to pass the "saved" lines in both a set and a list. If the newly clicked line is not in the set, append to the list and set. Otherwise, ignore.